# Is there a black hole information paradox in string theory?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, black-holes, string-theory

In string theory there is, for several black hole-like objects, a precise way to account for the microstates which make up the macroscopic Bekenstein-Hawking entropy. For instance for the black brane made of a bound state of $Q_1$ D1- and $Q_5$ D5-branes wrapped on $T^4 \times S^1$ the (1,5) and (5,1) open strings provide the leading contribution to the entropy at large charges, which is exactly $A/4$.

How, if at all, is the information paradox solved in this example or examples like this? What is the mechanism by which a pure in-state evolves into a thermal density matrix out-state-- and what happens in between?

Comment: The objects in string theory for which actual counting of the mircrostates is possible are (necessarily) supersymmetric, which implies that they have extremal charges, which in turn implies that their Hawking temperature is zero. Consequently, they don't evaporate, and there is no information paradox to begin with.

Comment: @mmeent But there are examples (such as in 9602043) of non-extremal microstate counting. Is there anything known about the information paradox in those settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no information paradox in string theory.

The example you cite (the D1-D5 system) is a stable BPS configuration, so no evaporation is taking place and all the black hole microstates (correctly computed by string theory) are evolving unitarily because string theory does not modify the rules of quantum mechanics ( see the beautiful Motl's post [Why string theory is quantum mechanics on steroids](https://motls.blogspot.com/2018/09/why-string-theory-is-quantum-mechanics.html)).

The fact that we perceive a black hole with a unique macroscopic state in the supergravity approximation as follows from higher-dimensional no-hair theorems ([sometimes violated in string theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4557)) is just an artifact produced by the fact that higher string modes are integrated out (by definition of zero-slope limit) but after all stringy modes are taken into account, no loss of coherence is possible.

But even if you allow evaporating black holes in string theory, information is preseverved because all the objects in string theory evolve unitarily. Even in time dependent situations, string theory predict the correct entropy computation ([beautiful example](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0204010)). Even if you take into account non-perturbative corrections , or you analize Calabi-Yau black holes outside the OSV regime (as was done in [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0504221) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0612067)) you will never find loss of coherence.

Arguably the most clear examples of the absence of information-like paradoxes in string theory are black holes realized within M(atrix) theory ([example](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9709114)) because the BFSS theory is manifestly an "ordinarily" quantum mechanical model.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer relates to the information loss problem. The problem is that it's impossible to locally identify event horizons. There are matter distributions with arbitrarily small curvature everywhere and at all past times, so the UV theory shouldn't even matter, in which there's already a macroscopic EH and it's already too late for information about the interior to escape. The distribution can even be homogeneous (FLRW) so there's no difference at all between a neighborhood of the horizon or interior or exterior. By what mechanism does the information leave? (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) "String theory doesn't modify the rules of QM" and "all the objects in string theory evolve unitarily" isn't a solution, it's part of the problem. If P=unitarity, Q=general covariance, R=light cone causality, the problem is $Q\wedge R\Rightarrow\neg P$. This contradiction isn't resolved by saying "we assumed P, therefore P is true and everything is fine."

Comment: @benrg The answer is related to the information paradox. The information paradox can be stated as the fact that a pure state that collapses into a black hole gets transformed to a mixed state after the end of the evaporation process, in other words, black hole physics evolves in a non-unitary way (that's why people say "information is lost"). Now consider the AdS/CFT correspondence (a string theoretical realization of holography) and a black hole on the bulk side. The theory of the bulk is actually defined by the theory at the boundary. This CFT is unitary even in presence of black holes.

Comment: @benrg The whole black hole physics can be identified purely in CFT terms and shown to evolve in a unitary way; that's an example of why there is no loss of information in string theory. Now, it is true that we haven't identified an explicit mechanism of how the information is retrieved in the bulk; that's a very interesting problem. But if information where lost in string theory, you should be able to detect a situation where a black hole evolves non-unitarily, that is a demostrably false statement in string theory. That's how my answer is related to the paradox.

Comment: @benrg There is no explicit solution, but there is a solution. Information is demonstrably preserved in the physics of black holes in string theory (a theory that actually explain the whole statistical mechanics of black holes).What is the solution that makes the information preservation explicit? that's a challenge, but again, information is preserved in string theory.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but it seems like claims that information is preserved are based on analyses of specific cases only. I've seen papers that try to refute Bell's theorem by outlining an experiment different from Bell's that can be explained with local hidden variables. That's how I feel about analyses of already-formed black holes in coordinates that presuppose the location of the event horizon. A real solution has to work in the hard cases. I think the answer must be some form of universal horizon complementarity, but that has its own no-go result (firewall paper etc.).

Comment: @benrg Yes, there is a case by case analysis. However the subject is nowadays enormous and it is remarkable how it perfectly works in an enormous class of examples. But yeah, what you say is valid and exciting. I love your phrase "universal horizon complementarity" and it remains to be seen if someone could achieve something of this sort within string theory (or any other theory).